# completar tabla de posiciones en java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy haciendo una tabla de posiciones de una liga de futbol. ya la hice y al momento de ejecutar, me ejecuta la tabla, en orden ascendente, tanto por puntos como por diferencia de goles(en caso de que 2 equipos tengan los mismos puntos, dichos equipos los ordena por mayor diferencia de goles). Y se ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
POS|    EQUIPO               | PJ |PG |PE |PP | GF |GC |DFG|PTS
 1.| Deportivo Cali          | 11 | 6 | 5 | 0 | 11 | 5 | 6 | 23
 2.| Independiente Santa Fe  | 11 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 14 | 7 | 7 | 22
 3.| Deportes Tolima         | 10 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 17 | 8 | 9 | 20
 4.| Jaguares de Cordoba     | 11 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 16 |10 | 6 | 20
 5.| La Equidad              | 11 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 11 | 8 | 3 | 19
 6.| Millonarios             | 10 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 14 |11 | 3 | 19
 7.| Atletico Nacional       | 10 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 19 | 9 |10 | 18
 8.| Junior                  | 11 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 14 |11 | 3 | 17
 9.| Independiente Medellin  | 11 | 4 | 5 | 2 |  9 | 7 | 2 | 17
10.| America de Cali         |  9 | 3 | 6 | 0 |  8 | 5 | 3 | 15
11.| Atletico Bucaramanga    | 10 | 3 | 3 | 4 |  9 | 8 | 1 | 12
12.| Deportivo Pasto         | 10 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 11 |12 |-1 | 12
13.| Patriotas               | 10 | 3 | 1 | 6 | 11 |14 |-3 | 10
14.| Envigado                | 10 | 1 | 6 | 3 |  8 |11 |-3 |  9
15.| Aguilas Doradas         | 10 | 1 | 5 | 4 |  7 |11 |-4 |  8
16.| Once Caldas             | 10 | 1 | 4 | 5 |  8 |12 |-4 |  7
17.| Boyaca Chico            | 11 | 2 | 1 | 8 |  7 |16 |-9 |  7
18.| Deportivo Pereira       | 11 | 1 | 3 | 7 |  9 |18 |-9 |  6
19.| Alianza Petrolera       | 10 | 0 | 3 | 7 |  5 |24 |-19|  3
```

Pero, el problema es este, como se puede ver en la tabla, en el puesto 5. Equipo La equidad y 6. Equipo Millonarios, tiene la misma cantidad de diferencia goles (+3), pero, por los goles a favor, el equipo de Millonarios tiene mas goles a favor que la Equidad, y por lo tanto, deberia ser al contrario (Millonarios puesto 5 y La equidad puesto 6), es por ello que acudo a ustedes, la verdad he intentado con implementar otro metodo if al compareTo, pero no me ejecuta. Este es el codigo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Futbol  {
    static class Equipo implements Comparable <Equipo>{
        public String equipo;
        public int pj;
        public int pg;
        public int pe;
        public int pp;
        public int gf;
        public int gc;
        public int dfg;
        public int pts;
 
        public Equipo(String equipo, int pj, int pg, int pe, int pp, int gf, int gc, int dfg, int 
        pts){
            this.equipo = equipo;
            this.pj = pj;
            this.pg = pg;
            this.pe = pe;
            this.pp = pp;
            this.gf = gf;
            this.gc = gc;
            this.dfg = dfg;
            this.pts = pts;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Equipo e) {
            Integer a = this.pts;
            Integer b = e.pts;
            if(b.compareTo(a) == 0){
                Integer x = this.dfg;
                Integer y = e.dfg;
                return y.compareTo(x);
        }
        
        
            return b.compareTo(a);
        
    }
       
    static void imprimirArrayEquipos(Equipo[] array){
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ".| " + array[i].equipo + " | " + array[i].pj + " | " + 
array[i].pg + " | " + array[i].pe + " | " + array[i].pp + " | " + array[i].gf + " | " + array[i].gc + 
" | " + array[i].dfg + " | " + array[i].pts);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Equipo[] arrayEquipos = new Equipo[19];
        arrayEquipos[0] = new Equipo("Aguilas Doradas", 10, 1, 5, 4, 7, 11, -4, 8);
        arrayEquipos[1] = new Equipo("Alianza Petrolera", 10, 0, 3, 7, 5, 24, -19, 3);
        arrayEquipos[2] = new Equipo("America de Cali", 9, 3, 6, 0, 8, 5, 3, 15);
        arrayEquipos[3] = new Equipo("Atletico Nacional", 10, 5, 3, 2, 19, 9, 10, 18);
        arrayEquipos[4] = new Equipo("Atletico Bucaramanga", 10, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1, 12);
        arrayEquipos[5] = new Equipo("Boyaca Chico", 11, 2, 1, 8, 7, 16, -9, 7);
        arrayEquipos[6] = new Equipo("Deportes Tolima", 10, 6, 2, 2, 17, 8, 9, 20);
        arrayEquipos[7] = new Equipo("Deportivo Cali", 11, 6, 5, 0, 11, 5, 6, 23);
        arrayEquipos[8] = new Equipo("Deportivo Pasto", 10, 2, 6, 2, 11, 12, -1, 12);
        arrayEquipos[9] = new Equipo("Deportivo Pereira", 11, 1, 3, 7, 9, 18, -9, 6);
        arrayEquipos[10] = new Equipo("Envigado", 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 11, -3, 9);
        arrayEquipos[11] = new Equipo("Independiente Medellin", 11, 4, 5, 2, 9, 7, 2, 17);
        arrayEquipos[12] = new Equipo("Independiente Santa Fe", 11, 6, 4, 1, 14, 7, 7, 22);
        arrayEquipos[13] = new Equipo("Jaguares de Cordoba", 11, 6, 2, 3, 16, 10, 6, 20);
        arrayEquipos[14] = new Equipo("Junior", 11, 5, 2, 4, 14, 11, 3, 17);
        arrayEquipos[15] = new Equipo("La Equidad", 11, 5, 4, 2, 11, 8, 3, 19);
        arrayEquipos[16] = new Equipo("Once Caldas", 10, 1, 4, 5, 8, 12, -4, 7);
        arrayEquipos[17] = new Equipo("Millonarios", 10, 6, 1, 3, 14, 11, 3, 19);
        arrayEquipos[18] = new Equipo("Patriotas", 10, 3, 1, 6, 11, 14, -3, 10);
   
        /*System.out.println("POS|    EQUIPO  |PJ|PG|PE|PP|GF|GC|DFG|PTS");
        imprimirArrayEquipos(arrayEquipos);*/
    
        Arrays.sort(arrayEquipos);
        System.out.println("POS|    EQUIPO  |PJ|PG|PE|PP|GF|GC|DFG|PTS");
        imprimirArrayEquipos(arrayEquipos);
    }
    }
}
```

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar, solo es esto y ya seria pasarlo a interfaz. garcias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu primer `if` en el `compareTo()` en vez de hacer un `return y.compareTo(x);` puedes añadir otro `if` para comparar que si la diferencia de goles son iguales, retornar por goles a favor.

Quedaría así tu método `compareTo()`:

```
public int compareTo(Equipo e) {
    Integer a = this.pts;
    Integer b = e.pts;
        
    if (b.compareTo(a) == 0) {
            
        Integer x = this.dfg;
        Integer y = e.dfg;
            
        if(y.compareTo(x) == 0) {
    
            Integer z = this.gf;
            Integer w = e.gf;
                
            return w.compareTo(z); 
        }else
            return y.compareTo(x);
    }

    return b.compareTo(a);
}
```

**Output:**

```
POS|    EQUIPO  |PJ|PG|PE|PP|GF|GC|DFG|PTS
1.| Deportivo Cali | 11 | 6 | 5 | 0 | 11 | 5 | 6 | 23
2.| Independiente Santa Fe | 11 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 14 | 7 | 7 | 22
3.| Deportes Tolima | 10 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 17 | 8 | 9 | 20
4.| Jaguares de Cordoba | 11 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 16 | 10 | 6 | 20
5.| Millonarios | 10 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 14 | 11 | 3 | 19
6.| La Equidad | 11 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 11 | 8 | 3 | 19  
7.| Atletico Nacional | 10 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 19 | 9 | 10 | 18
8.| Junior | 11 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 14 | 11 | 3 | 17
9.| Independiente Medellin | 11 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 9 | 7 | 2 | 17
10.| America de Cali | 9 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 15
11.| Atletico Bucaramanga | 10 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 12
12.| Deportivo Pasto | 10 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 11 | 12 | -1 | 12
13.| Patriotas | 10 | 3 | 1 | 6 | 11 | 14 | -3 | 10
14.| Envigado | 10 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 11 | -3 | 9
15.| Aguilas Doradas | 10 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 7 | 11 | -4 | 8
16.| Once Caldas | 10 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 8 | 12 | -4 | 7
17.| Boyaca Chico | 11 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 16 | -9 | 7
18.| Deportivo Pereira | 11 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 18 | -9 | 6
19.| Alianza Petrolera | 10 | 0 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 24 | -19 | 3
```

Comment: GRACIAS, LO QUE VEO QUE HICE MAL FUE COLOCAR LA CONDICION IF APARTE DE LA CONDICION DE DIFERENCIA GOLES, EN VEZ DE PASARLO ADEENTRO DE ESA CONDICIONAL.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, Por favor no olvides votar positivo mí respuesta y marcar el check en gris que aparece debajo